# Does HTTPonly or Secure Header works on request or response?

Tags: security, header, httponly

HTTPonly or Secure flag header works on HTTP request or HTTP response? 
Most of the time I see it on response.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Microsoft Developer Network, HttpOnly is an additional flag included in a Set-Cookie HTTP response header. Please check https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly

If the HttpOnly flag (optional) is included in the HTTP response header, the cookie cannot be accessed through client side script (again if the browser supports this flag).

And It's mitigating the most common XSS attack using HttpOnly

Answer (score 0):

XSS like alert(document.cookie) can be executed if HTTPonly or Secure flag not available in response header, you can set these headers from web application server configuration. Once you set headers user's browser will get these headers in response and browser will deny any java script to get cookie data. So these headers are response.